# jsp pages displaying junk characters in non english languages

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Main JSP page say jsp1 which includes two JSP pages (jsp2, jsp3). All the strings in these pages come from property files.

The non-english property files are converted using native2ascii

native2ascii –encoding="8859-1" lang.properties lang1.properties

All the JSP pages have 
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

Now when main jsp page(jsp1) gets displayed, we see garbled characters in a few strings of jsp2 and jsp3. Till now I have seen this happening to Russian, Korean, Japanese language strings. And it happens on a random string.

Does any one have an idea what could be wrong

**Updating with more details**

The string in rus_utf8.proeperties is

`Щелкните <strong>УСТАНОВИТЬ СЕЙЧАС</strong> и сохраните файл в некотором расположении`

After Conversion using native2Ascii, String in rus.properties is

`\u0429\u0435\u043b\u043a\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435 <strong>\u0423\u0421\u0422\u0410\u041d\u041e\u0412\u0418\u0422\u042c \u0421\u0415\u0419\u0427\u0410\u0421</strong> \u0438 \u0441\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b \u0432 \u043d\u0435\u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043c \u0440\u0430\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0438.`

In JSP we use struts `<s:text>` to load the string from property file

In firefox the string got displayed as

`��елкните УСТАНОВИТЬ СЕЙЧАС и сохраните файл в некотором расположении.`

The char `Щ` got garbled. Same String in some other place in the page got displayed properly.

Answer (score 8):

> The non-english property files are converted using native2ascii
>
> ```
> native2ascii –encoding="8859-1" lang.properties lang1.properties
> ```

This is invalid. It should have been

```
native2ascii –encoding ISO-8859-1 lang.properties lang1.properties
```

Apart from the syntax error which you have there (which should immediately have aborted native2ascii), the ISO-8859-1 encoding can impossibly be correct for Russian, Korean and Japanese strings. The ISO-8859-1 encoding does not cover those characters at all. Assuming that you saved it as UTF-8, then you should be using

```
native2ascii –encoding UTF-8 lang.properties lang1.properties
```

This way the native2ascii will convert from an UTF-8 `lang.properties` to an ISO-8859-1 compatible `lang1.properties`. The native2ascii will **always** convert to ASCII. The `-encoding` attribute concerns the encoding of the source file, not the target file.

As to the JSP pages, just a

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

ought to be sufficient, per http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Update** as per your update with the examples. Everything is actually working right. It only look much like that the UTF-8 BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) is the culprit. Notepad adds it by default. Try creating the properties file in another editor instead like Eclipse.

Comment: The blog you posted is very useful

Comment: This dint solve my issue. Now this is what I have

RUS property file that I had contains Russian strings, and is stored in UTF8 without BOM (notepad++). 

I did 

native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 rus_utf8.properties rus.properties

All my JSP pages have 
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %> 
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

My Tomcat server.xml has
<Connector (...) URIEncoding="UTF-8" />

I have a filter which does 
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 

Now when I see the JSP page in firefox, I still get a few characters garbled with "�". What else could go wrong?

Comment: Are it all characters or only a few? Please update your question to include some words of the rus_utf8.properties, the converted representation in rus.properties and the result in browser.

Comment: I have updated with details. The words that are shown in bold, actually are enclosed with <strong> tags in property file

Comment: I see. UTF-8 is actually working fine. It look much like that the UTF-8 BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) is the culprit. Notepad adds it by default. Try creating the properties file in another editor instead like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you and I also tried the similar solutions but they didn't work. Hence I suspected that it may not be an issue with JSP config but rather it is a config issue with my tomcat.

I found this on a Chinese site, https://openhome.cc/Gossip/Encoding/Servlet.html: `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`. It worked for me. I added this before my `request.getParameter();`.